# How to create an image with exact width of string of text using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to create an image form text string but I don't want to fix its size in initial. Its size should be change according to string length also I want to add background-color and border-radius in image. How Can I do it.?

For example if I have text "9627" then after creating its image it should be look like with border radius and with background-color-

[image]

I have tried many codes but all codes fix the image size first and then put text in that image. It does not work well with varying string length.

**EDIT:-**
I recently tried this code. Still it is showing an broken image.

```
<?php 

    function calculateTextBox($text,$fontFile,$fontSize,$fontAngle) { 
        $rect = imagettfbbox($fontSize,$fontAngle,$fontFile,$text); 
        $minX = min(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6])); 
        $maxX = max(array($rect[0],$rect[2],$rect[4],$rect[6])); 
        $minY = min(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7])); 
        $maxY = max(array($rect[1],$rect[3],$rect[5],$rect[7])); 

        return array( 
         "left"   => abs($minX) - 1, 
         "top"    => abs($minY) - 1, 
         "width"  => $maxX - $minX, 
         "height" => $maxY - $minY, 
         "box"    => $rect 
        ); 
    } 


    $text_string    = "Hello World"; 
    //$font_ttf        = "./fonts/arial.ttf"; 
    $font_size        = 22; 
    $text_angle        = 0; 
    $text_padding    = 10; // Img padding - around text 

    $the_box        = calculateTextBox($text_string,  $font_size, $text_angle); 

    $imgWidth    = $the_box["width"] + $text_padding; 
    $imgHeight    = $the_box["height"] + $text_padding; 

    $image = imagecreate($imgWidth,$imgHeight); 
    imagefill($image, imagecolorallocate($image,200,200,200)); 

    $color = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0); 
    imagettftext($image, 
        $font_size, 
        $text_angle, 
        $the_box["left"] + ($imgWidth / 2) - ($the_box["width"] / 2), 
        $the_box["top"] + ($imgHeight / 2) - ($the_box["height"] / 2), 
        $color, 
        $text_string); 

    header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
    imagepng($image); 
    imagedestroy($image); 

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use imagettfbbox assuming you are using true type fonts:
[link here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)